# How to update database-schema in Cakephp in 2.3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-schema, cakephp-2.3

I am reading the following documentation of Cakephp. I am trying to add a field in a database and let CakePHP know about this.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html

It says:

> To later rebuild the database schema from your previously made schema.php file run:

```
Console/cake schema create
```

I have searched *app/Config/Schema* to find the previous file and see what is inside it, but I couldn't find anything.

How can cakePHP's database connection still work without it's schema? Or do I understand this completely wrong ?

Comment: At run time CakePHP doesn't use schema files - it interrogates the db to know what is the schema of used tables. Generally that functionality is only used as a developer aide to dump the schema to file for reference/to import in a clean install.

Comment: @AD7six So how do I update this part so it knows a change is made? Do I need to initiate that interrogation ?

Comment: The only thing you normally need to do to let CakePHP know there are new fields in the db is clear the cache - as that's where it stores the db schema. In development the cache lifetime in 10 seconds, so you may find the cache is never stale. This is the reason you'll see describe queries in your sql log during development - the cache expires frequently and Cake runs describe queries as required, caching the result, for future reference (in production for 99 days).

Comment: Aah alright, So I should clear the Cache. Thank you. I will look that up. I geuss I can't just delete everything from the cache folder.

Comment: Yes you can, if it's in the cache folder it's transient info that'll get recreated. Please self-answer your question with your conclusion/findings.